# Media Query not working

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries, frontend

The CSS is in a .scss file and being minified with Gulp which works without any issues. I'm testing the responsiveness is Chrome(resizing the webpage). I have added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

HTML

```
<div class="container text-center" >
            <h1 class="banner-title">Welcome Refugees</h1>      
</div>
```

.SCSS

```
.banner-title {
    margin-top: 275px; 
    font-size: 700%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) 
  and (max-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

.banner-title {
    font-size: 500%;
}

}
```

Is this a common issue?

Comment: what exactly is the issue?  you don't see the font-size change?  does your device/screen meet all those criteria in the media query (especially that `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3` one)?

Comment: Please note -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio is non-standard – ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this on a blog
http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32

```css
profile-pic {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .profile-pic {
    width: 100px;
    float: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .profile-pic {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. All I needed to do was get rid of the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3` which was also noted by @andi . Silly mistake. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using $sm, $md, $lg, $xl as SASS variables to represent different sizes.

```
$sm = 600; // @media screen queries don't compile correctly
$sm = 600px; // @media screen queries work as expected
```

Hopefully this helps someone