# Problem with responsive design using @media only screen

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, media-queries, screen-size

I have a problem with understanding how `@media only screen` works. I have three screen sizes:

```
1) @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
2) @media only screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1250px)
3) @media only screen and (min-width: 1250px)
```

I want to make that one element would be shown only on large screen size (3), so I wrote:
`display: none` on 1) and 2) screens and `display: block` on 3) screen.

I also have three style files for each screen size which are put into the main file like this:

```
@import "large-screen";
@import "medium-screen";
@import "small-screen";
```

And the small-screen size file overwrites the others:

[image: inspect]

I don't understand how it can overwrite if it's set to `@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)`, doesn't `max-width 640px` mean that this code will work when screen is smaller than `640px`? Can someone explain me how this work and how I should write that my element would be displayed only on large screen. Thank you!

Comment: Try reversing the order of your @import statements.

Comment: And check out this answer about the order of media queries and the 'cascading' nature of cascading style sheets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790321/why-does-the-order-of-media-queries-matter-in-css

Comment: Then the element is shown on all screen sizes, it overwrites all other screen sizes, and display none: for 1)  2)  screens does not work.

Comment: Your original code works for me (see codepen here: https://codepen.io/newstaircase/pen/poNvRJL) so the problem might be elsewhere, e.g. HTML not matching up with CSS, other CSS overriding what you've done. Please could you show more code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989147/media-query-not-working)